# tolower() Function not Working in C99

Tags: c, cs50, tolower

I am using the CS50 appliance from Harvard and trying to make a character lowercase. I am trying to use the `tolower()` function but when I try to use it I get the message `implicit declaration of function 'tolower' is invalid in C99`. Anyone care to elaborate on why I would be getting this message. I have included `stdio.h` as well as `string.h`.

Comment: You didn't include the header and, in C99, functions are not assumed to be valid and return an int if there is no definition.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To use `tolower` in C99, use `#include <ctype.h>`

It is not an I/O function and it doesn't operate on strings (it operates on characters), so it's not in `stdio` or `string`.

Comment: Well this has corrected the problem of calling an unidentified function but now when I try to just say `character[0]="A";` i get trouble. Any ideas? Says something about pointers and integers. For reference I declared `char character[2];`.

Comment: character[0] = 'A' should work. By doing character[0] = "A", you are trying to assign a string to a character, which is not allowed.

Comment: @ChapmIndustries "A" is `const char *`, so the assignment is dealign with `const char *`, a pointer type, assigned to `char`, an integral type.

Answer (score 5):

`tolower` is defined in `ctype.h`. That is the file you should be including:

```
#include <ctype.h>
```

will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's defined in `ctype.h` not in those headers that you mentioned.